# Using junction table with duplicate ids causing confusiont with a sql query within a php foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, loops, foreach

I have a variable in $_POST that looks like this:

```
[genre_id] => Array
   (
       [0] => 1
       [1] => 3
   )
```

I have a block of php code like this:

```
foreach ($_POST["genre_id"] as $key => $value) {
  $genre_query = "UPDATE books_genres SET genre_id = $value WHERE book_id = $book_id";
  $genre_result = mysqli_query($connection, $genre_query);
  if ($genre_result && mysqli_affected_rows($connection) >= 0) {
   echo("Genre Update: Sucess<br>");
  } else {
    echo("Genre Update: Fail<br>");
  }
}
```

The table called `books_genres` is an junction table because of a many to many relationship. This means some of the `$book_id` will be duplicated. What's clearly happening is that each and every row with the specified `book_id` is being updated each time. 
 Should I have another column in my books_genres table? Even then I'm not sure how I would reference that index? Or should I be writing the query different somehow?

Comment: Typically you don't update a junction table. You would remove the old values and insert new ones. If you want to do this type of update you would need to include the "old" genre_id as an additional predicate in your where clause so it knows which genre_id you are wanting to update.

Comment: @sean_lange so I would update both the books and genres tables each then have code that updates the books_genres table separately? Am I understanding what you are saying is more standard?

Comment: No. The point of a junction table is that you don't need to update anything ever. It has the key from both tables right? The key isn't changing in your table is it? Unless you have denormalized your structures you really don't need to update junction tables except in pretty rare scenarios. If a given book was classified as "classical" and then gets reclassified as "horror" you would delete the classical entry and insert the horror entry. Perhaps posting the ddl and some sample data would help in explaining this.

Comment: Okay so I'm deleting and then adding new entries on the junction table, no updates. I can see how that solves my problem. Thank you

Comment: @SeanLange I wish I could mark your comment as correct as it solved my problem completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of a junction table is that you don't need to update anything ever. It has the key from both tables right? The key isn't changing in your table is it? Unless you have denormalized your structures you really don't need to update junction tables except in pretty rare scenarios. If a given book was classified as "classical" and then gets reclassified as "horror" you would delete the classical entry and insert the horror entry. Perhaps posting the ddl and some sample data would help in explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

> What's clearly happening is that each and every row with the specified
>   book_id is being updated each time.

But that is exactly what you've asked MySQL engine to do!

Please remember, the SQL is a **declarative** language, not imperative.
So instead of showing the code, **declare** you intentions!

Tell yourself and us what you intend to update.

In other words, define a record set the "update" should hit.
Having that, you'd easily derive the "where" clause you need to narrow the operation.